# How to propagate the parent's click event in Pyside2 as if I have clicked the button directly while hovering over it?

Tags: pyqt, pyside2

How to propagate the parent's click event in Pyside2 as if **I have clicked the button directly** while hovering over it?

This is a very peculiar problem, and I haven't been able to find even a question like this.

A button is positioned on the main UI window. When clicked, it hides the parent window, and spawns another window at that position. I need it to work with a single click, for example, I want to press the button, and not release the mouse immediately, but hover over a certain part of the newly spawned window and then release it.

This works perfectly fine if I click the button directly , but the problem is I need to click the button from the main UI window.
I am doing it by sending "mousePressEvent" from the main UI window to the child widget's "mousePressEvent", like this:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):   #parent mouse press event
    #----
    #----
    self.FocusedButton.mousePressEvent(event) # child widget
```

When I activate the button from the mainUI window, the window is immediately hidden and the new window is spawned. However, since I haven't performed mouse release yet, I am stuck into the parent's mouse press event loop. The mouse doesn't invoke paint event and doesn't register mouseMoveEvent until I release the click because the mainUI window is hidden and mouse tracking doesn't work any more.

- I have tried setting the flags of the window in every way, (QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents,True ) for example, but none of it worked.
- The main UI window inherits from "QtWidgets.QWidget" and does not have the clicked method.

Comment: Let me see if I understood your problem: you want to receive a mouse *press* event on a widget, then hide its window, show another, and all of that while the button is still pressed, then when the user finally releases the mouse button, let the second window/widget receive that event?

Comment: https://imgur.com/wvnn5Du

Comment: Please *explain* the concept either in a comment or, better, by expanding your question. The image/animation might be useful, but a *text* explanation is better, especially if the original question might seem confusing.

Comment: On the video there are two tries, the first is when the click lands directly on the button, and then it works as intended, but a button is also hilighted by the direction of the mouse from the center of the window. If hilighted, a mouse click on empty space it will send the mouse press event to the child button.
The button in turn summons it's child window.  the child window also determines the next button by the angle of rotation -  with mousetracking.

Comment: Sorry but your explanation is still not clear, so, please, answer my first question and try to summarize the *concept*: do not go too deep into details about your *final* expectation, but get to the point of the basic issue itself (which is what I asked). It's not clear if the video refers to an existing program or *yours*; in the second case, then it seems that you don't even need to "change window", but only *switch* to another page (possibly using a QStackedWidget).

Comment: If the button is clicked indirectly, there is mousepress event on the main UI window that will send the event to the button, and hide itself.

What I want is to do that with just one mouse click, and one mouse release.

The problem is, while the button is pressed indirectly (on empty space), I am still in the mousepressevent of the main UI window, and since it is now hidden, mouse tracking doesn't work.
I want to send a "mouse click event "to the child button as if I am clicking it directly.
I hope I've made my self clear now, and thanks for the time.

Comment: Clarification: I am trying to make a pyside2 UI for autodesk Maya

Comment: So, as said, why don't you try to use a QStackedWidget on *one* single window instead? This will certainly make things easier, as you don't need to switch windows, but just the *pages*, so that mouse event management would be much easier.

Comment: To be honest, I am new to this, and I wasn't aware of QStackedWidget, I might try to rebuild it with that. Thanks.